# What is a good way to show the effect of replication in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replication

We have to show a difference to show the advantages of using replication. We have two computers, linked by teamviewer so we can show our class what we are doing exactly.

- Is it possible to show a difference in performance? (How long it takes to execute certain queries?)
- What sort queries should we test? (in other words, where is the difference between using/not using replication the biggest)
- How should we fill our database? How much data should be there?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to the above questions depends on factors such as which storage engine you are using, size of the database, as well as your chosen replication architecture.

I don't think replication will have much of an impact on query execution for simple master->slave architecture. If however, you have an architecture where there are two masters: one handling writes, replicating to another master which exclusively handles reads, and then replication to a slave which handles backups, then you are far more likely to be able to present some of the more positive scenarios. Have a read up on locks and storage engines, as this might influence your choices.

One simple way to show how Replication can be positive is to demonstrate a simple backup strategy. E.g. Taking hourly backups on a master server itself can bring the underlying application to a complete halt for the duration of the backup (Taking backups using mysqldump locks the tables so that no read/write operations can occur). Whereas replicating to a slave, then taking backups from there negates this affect.

If you want to show detailed statistics, it's probably better to look into some benchmarking/profiling tools (sysbench,mysqlslap,sql-bench to name a few). This can become quite complex though.
Also might be worth looking at the Percona Toolkit and the Percona monitoring plugins here: http://www.percona.com/software/

Comment: When using a master-master architecture, is it possible to devide a SELECT query with a limit?

For instance: "SELECT * FROM .. LIMIT 0,100" on the first, and "SELECT * FROM .. LIMIT 100, 100" on the second? I could see an improvement in performance in comparison to a single query: "SELECT * FROM .. LIMIT 0,200"

We are using a database with ~100.000 entries, an old database for http://www.funda.nl/ (you can look up / buy houses there).

edit: pressing enter commits a comment instead of ending a line.. and I can only edit for 5 minutes. annoying :))

Comment: I guess there's nothing stopping you doing two selects across two masters. Using LIMIT might not be as fast as it sounds: Each of these queries scans all the rows from an index before returning your defined 100 rows. Queries like this have a lousy response time and make mysqld do too much work. It might help in terms of spreading the load. However, bear in mind how you will deal with the result set, as you could be doubling complexity and network utilization. 100,000 entries is quite a small amount of data to consider doing that.

Comment: Individual `SELECT` queries are unlikely to go noticeably faster. If you want to demonstrate the performance benefits of replication, one way to show this is by sending thousands of queries per second to a database server. Replication improves scalability not query performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication-intro.html) has several advantages:

- **Robustness** is increased with a master/slave setup. In the event of problems with the master, you can switch to the slave as a backup
- **Better response time** for clients can be achieved by splitting the load for processing client queries between the master and slave servers
- Another benefit of using replication is that you can perform **database backups using a slave server** without disturbing the master.

Using replication always a safe thing to do you should be replicating your Production server always incase of failure it will be helpful.

You can show `seconds_behind_master` value while showing replication performance, this shows indication of how “late” the slave is this value should not be more than 600-800 seconds but network latency does matter here.
Make sure that `Master` and `Slave` servers are configured correctly now 
You can stop `slave` server and let `Master` server has some updates/inserts (bulk inserts) happening and now start `slave` server you will see larger `seconds_behind_master` value it should be keep on decreasing till reaches `0` value.

There is a tool called [MONyog - MySQL Monitor and Advisor](http://webyog.com) which shows Replication status in real-time.
[image]

Also what kind of replication to use whether statement based or row based has been explained here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html